# Hive not recognizing underscore in path

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I'm trying to import some CSV file on HDFS to Hive.

```
Create table if not exists mytable (
    customer_id BIGINT,
    device_serial_number STRING,
    device_software_version BIGINT,
    device_type BIGINT,
    market_place BIGINT,
    reader_software_version BIGINT,
    source_string_list_version INT,
    message_datetime STRING,
    message_string STRING    
  )
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
Location '/hive/.../output001/_se';
select * from mytable
```

I got error using this

```
java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist....
```

If I get rid of "_", using

```
Location '/hive/.../output001/se';
```

It works fine.

I understand that one way to get around is to output my data to a folder without underscore but unfortunately I cannot do that.

So is this underscore really the problem and how do I make Hive recognize it?

Thanks.

Comment: The file starting with . or _ are hidden files. What you could do to work around this issue is to read the source of
FileInputFormat#listStatus(…) and @Override and re-implement it.

Comment: I had my hadoop job output to a folder without underscore in its name.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static final PathFilter hiddenFileFilter = new PathFilter() {
        public boolean accept(Path p) {
            String name = p.getName();
            return !name.startsWith("_") && !name.startsWith(".");
        }
    };
```

Comment: hive think _ and . is the hiddle file.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please can you include an explanation of your answer.